# org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using spring boot and and spring data in my project and i have two classes:

```
class Mission implements Serializable { private static final long 
serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long              id;
private String            departure;
private String            arrival;
private Boolean           isFreeWayEnabled;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "mission" )
private List<Station>     stations;
// getters and setters
}
```

and the second class is :

```
@Entity
public class Station implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long              id;
private String            station;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JsonBackReference
private Mission           mission;
 //getters and setters
 }
```

Methode which add Mission:

```
public Mission addMision( Mission mission ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Mission mission = getMissionById( mission.getId() );
    for ( Station station : mission.getStations() ) {
        station.setMission( mission );
        stationRepository.save( station );
    }
    return missionRepository.save( mission );
}
```

when i tried to add a new Mission it gives the error above heres Json Object :

> {"departure":"fff","arrival":"ffff","isFreeWayEnabled":false,"stations":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mession is not persisted, you need either to save it or to cascade it in Station, also you have a bidirectional relation, which means each part of the relation should have reference to the other part
So in your Mission class initialize the station list

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "mission" )
private List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add the cascade in your Station

```
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
@JsonBackReference
 private Mission           mission;
```

then in your add logic put a reference of each part of the relation to the other

```
public Mission addMision( Mission mission ) {

 List<Station> stations = mission.getStations();
 mission.setStations(new ArrayList<Station>());
 for ( Station station : stations ) {
    station.setMission( mission );
    mission.getStations.add(station);
    mission = stationRepository.save( station ).getMission();
}
 return mission;
}
```

Comment: Ok I fixed but it still gives another error which is :Unable to find com.carpooling.entity.Station with id 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.carpooling.entity.Station with id 2"

Comment: you do not need to save the mission again after cascading it , just return the original mission

Comment: because i have to things to save the first one is the mission and the second one is its stations(mission's stations) anyway i tried what you suggest but it still give the same error

Comment: Yes i did but the same error:Unable to find com.carpooling.entity.Station with id 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.carpooling.entity.Station with id 2"

Comment: so what do u think ser to fix this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151924/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-imsi-imsi).